# Change numbering of figures from within section to within chapter mid document

Tags: captions

I would like to change from within section to within chapter numbering of figures and tables after the first chapter of my document. However, entering `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} \counterwithin{table}{chapter}` mid document does not work. Using the starred option does count within chapters, but resets the formatting of the caption numbers to "Figure 2.1.1, 2.1.2, etc...".

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

% Setup caption numbering for first chapter
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

% Setup caption numbering for subsequent chapters
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}


\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

see if this solution work for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
\ifnum\value{chapter}=1
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\else
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}
\fi}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\ifnum\value{chapter}=1
    \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection-\arabic{table}}
\else
    \renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter-\arabic{table}}
\fi}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}


\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use of `chngcntr` and macros `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` and  `\counterwithin{table}{chapter}` in this case doesn't work as you expected. Even with the use of `etoolbox` as I suggest in the *mwe* above. Therefore I use redefinition of `\thefigure` and `\thetable` depending on chapter number.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to call the relevant `\counterwithout` instructions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

% Setup caption numbering for first chapter
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

% Setup caption numbering for subsequent chapters
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}


\section{Section 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]