# ContinuedFloat not working - ShareLatex

Tags: graphics, subcaption, sharelatex

I'm using ShareLatex to write my thesis and right now I need 16 images divided by 3 pages with the same caption. The images should be on pairs of two for being able to compare. I don't want any subcaption on the bottom, I only want the reference (a), (b), (c)....till (p) and that's why I am using the `\continuedfloat` command that for some reason isn't working.

I tried to put the command in different places but it never worked.

I need this on the 3 pages but with the references well done.

[image]
My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5a}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:441}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5b}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:442}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5c}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:443}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5d}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:444}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5e}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:445}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}   
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5f}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:446}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5g}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:447}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5h}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:448}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\caption{Comparação}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: So, after successfully compiled this code in a new blank project, the problem must be in another place, probably in the main .tex. I leave here the main parts of the file:

```
\documentclass[


docdegree=msc,        % phd(*), phdplan, phdprop, msc, mscplan, bsc
  school=nova/fct,      % nova/fct(*), nova/fcsh, nova/ims, ul/ist, ul/fc
  lang=pt,              % en(*), fr, it, pt
  coverlang=pt,         % defaults to main language
  copyrightlang=pt,     % defaults to main language
  fontstyle=kpfonts,    % baskervaldx bookman charter ebgaramond fbb fourier garamond
                        % heuristica kpfonts(*) libertine mathpazo1 mathpazo2 newcent
                        % newpx newtx 
  chapstyle=elegant,    % bianchi bluebox brotherton dash default elegant(*) ell ger 
                        % hansen ist jenor lyhne madsen pedersen veelo vz14 vz34 vz43
  otherlistsat=front,   % front(*), back
  aftercover=false,     % false=don't true=include the aftercover file (even if exists)
  linkscolor=darkblue,  % darkblue, black (Set to 'black' for PRINTING)
  printcommittee=true,  % set to 'false' from submitted versins who should not have 
                        % the list of committee memebers
  spine=true,          % (Set to 'true' for PRINTING the book spine)
  cdcover=true,         % (Set to 'true' for PRINTING the CD cover)
  biblatex={            % Options for biblatex (see biblatex documentation)
    backend=biber,     % use bibtex if possible
    style=numeric, % numeric(*), alphabetic, authoryear, bwl-FU
    sortcites=true,     % If numeric, sort cites by crescent order
    sorting=none,        % none, nyt(*), ynt
    %%% other options for biblatex
    maxbibnames=99,     % Never use 'et al' in the bibliography
    giveninits=true,    % render all first and middle names as initials
    hyperref=true       % Hyperlinks in citations: true(*) false
  },
  memoir={              % See the 'memoir' documentation
    showtrims,          % DEBUG
    a4paper,            % the paper size/format
    11pt,               % 10pt, 11pt(*), 12pt
    final,              % draft, final  <= Replace 'draft' with 'final' in final version
  },
  media=screen,  
]{novathesis}

\usepackage{booktabs}    % Beautiful simple tables
\usepackage{paralist}    % To enable customizble enumerates

%% IMPORTANT (consider removing/commenting)
%\usepackage{colortbl}    % Use colors in background of table cells
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}  % To register TODO notes in the text
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3.25cm}


%\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Maybe it's the order of the packages?

The document class I am using is a template created by a professor from my university many years ago.

The full template it's available for download here [Github Nova Thesis](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis/tree/master/LaTeX).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Continuedfloat reflects the caption, it resets the figure counter, but it is the caption that steps that counter up in the first place, you'll need a caption on each (most may just say continued). Btw for a user, it is not particularly nice having to turn several pages to find the main caption. The text ought to be in the first caption.

Comment: Btw by resetting I mean: continuedfloat steps the figure counter down by one, such that when caption steps it up, we're still at the same number. I'm not sure if the subcaption counter is supported by continuedfloat, not at pc so haven't tested your code. Btw: next tome please post a complete document but minimal) that makes it a lot easier for others to copy and test your example. Having to guess class and preamble does not encourage others to help. As test images you can just use `\rule{4cm}{4cm}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: By the way, I just edited your code

Comment: @BambOo you probably should not have added the documentclass line, from the OPs information we do not know if the article class is being used. It is a fair assumption for an mwe but we not know and that part should be fixed by the op. I agree on the rest of the edit.

Comment: @RafaelSantos I must confess that I don't understand what exactly your problem is. Is the outcome of your example document ok but you want to get rid of the sub-captions? If yes I guess the easiest way to do so is putting `\captionsetup[sub]{box=empty}` at the beginning of every affected figure.

Comment: @daleif, I agree with your remark regarding the documentclass, which is why I also added the welcome comment and warned the OP I had modified his snippet

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I think I wasn't clear with my question... I need that the subcaptions ((a),(b),(c),...) continue from one page to another. Right now I have 6 subfigures in one page from (a) to (f) and in the next page I have another 6 subfigures and instead of having the subcaptions (g) to (l) I have again (a) to (f). 'code' \ContinuedFloat doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @RafaelSantos as said before, it is generally not a good practice to use the same caption for three different pages, there is probably a simpler way. Can you explain why you need this ?

Comment: @BambOo I have 8 pictures from an article that I need to compare side by side with my experimental results. I thought this was the best way to do it. If I can't manage to succeed probably I will have to do it two per two. But I think this way, the same caption for all with different letters per case, is better.

Comment: IMHO if you need to compare article vs experimental for let's say 8 different parameters, you should probably do : Fig1 Parameter 1, (a) Article (b) Experimental, Fig 2 Parameter 2 ... and so on

Comment: If it was that way with parameters yes, it would make sense to do that. The think is that it isn't... They are 8 sequential shots of a velocity field. 8 from the article and 8 from my results

Comment: @RafaelSantos We do need a document which actually shows the problem. If I compile the document from your question, I get the 16 sub-figures numbered continuously as (a) to (p).

Comment: So, I just tested the code I had in a new blank project because you said it had worked with you yes, it worked with me too this time. The problem must be in the document class or on the packages used. I am going to update my question with more information.

Comment: @RafaelSantos Thanks, this way I could reproduce and fix your problem. See my (new) answer below.

Comment: Thank you so much! @AxelSommerfeldt It worked! It's taking more time to compile now but that's a minor problem. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `novathesis` document class you use is based on the `memoir` document class and this document class offers its own sub-caption functions. These functions do not interfere with the `subcaption` package as long as they don't get activated. Unfortunately the `novathesis` document class does activate these functions by using:

```
\newsubfloat{figure}
```

So a modified version of the example document from your question which shows the problem is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5a}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:441}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5b}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:442}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5c}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:443}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5d}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:444}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5e}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:445}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}   
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5f}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:446}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5g}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:447}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5h}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:448}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\caption{Comparação}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem: The `novathesis` documument class says "Hey, I want to use the sub-caption feature of the memoir class!" but by loading the `subcaption` package you say "Hey, I want to use the sub-caption feature of the caption package!".

Since the user usually only does one of them this does not fit the concept of the `subcaption` package. However, I have created an issue in my bug tracker [1] and this situation will be detected and handled correctly by future versions of the `subcaption` package. Until then, you could add the following work-around to your code, right after loading the `subcaption` package:

```
\makeatletter
\@cons\caption@subtypelist{{figure}}
\makeatother
```

Complete example document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\@cons\caption@subtypelist{{figure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5a}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:441}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5b}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:442}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5c}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:443}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5d}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:444}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5e}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:445}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}   
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5f}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:446}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5g}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:447}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5h}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:448}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}}

\caption{Comparação}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As an alternative you could use the sub-caption features offered by the `memoir` document class and avoid using the `subcaption` package.

[1] https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/25

Comment: Fixed with caption v3.4e (2020-01-02), so the work-around is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**
from your comments can be concluded that in your document you use figure/table numbering within sections. mwe below is extended with similar features.

`\ContinuedFloat` decrement counter `figure` and not interfere in counter for sub captions. it is increased  at each `subcaptionbox` till to the last figure included in `\ContinuedFloat`. referencing works as is desired (and expected), for example:

```
see figures \ref{subfig:5a}, \ref{subfig:5e} and \ref{subfig:448} on figure \ref{fig:label}.
```

and

```
see figures \ref{subfig:2a} and \ref{subfig:2b} on figure \ref{fig:test}.
```

gives

[image]

[image]

complete code, which consider [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) comments:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{booktabs}    % Beautiful simple tables
\usepackage{paralist}    % To enable customizble enumerates

%% IMPORTANT (consider removing/commenting)
%\usepackage{colortbl}    % Use colors in background of table cells
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}  % To register TODO notes in the text
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3.25cm}


%\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{forth chapter}
numbering of images is within chapter ...
\section{first section}
    \begin{figure}[htb]

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5a}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:441}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5b}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:442}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5c}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:443}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Comparação}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5d}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:444}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5e}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:445}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5f}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:446}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Comparação (cont.)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\ContinuedFloat
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5g}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:447}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:5h}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:448}}{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}}

\caption{Comparação (cont)}
\end{figure}

see figures \ref{subfig:5a}, \ref{subfig:5e} and \ref{subfig:448} on figure \ref{fig:label}.

\section{fifth section}
numbering of images is within section ...

\begin{figure}[htb]
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:2a}}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig:2b}}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{test ...}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
see figures \ref{subfig:2a} and \ref{subfig:2b} on figure \ref{fig:test}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the `caption` package variant of `\ContinuedFloat` does not decrement the figure counter. (But the variant offered by the `subfig` package does.)

Comment: ...instead `\ContinuedFloat` is suppressing the incremention of the figure counter if `\caption` is used. So it should not make a difference in the counting of the sub-figures if extra `\caption`s are added here.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, for successive numbering and referencing of sub captions it is not necessary to have caption in the each figure. captions only indicate to which figure belong showed sub figures. or i misunderstood you?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt that's probably my bad, I wrote that on a comment above.

Comment: @Zarko If I try to that with the same picture names I get **see figure 4.9a 4.9c 4.9d on 4.9** . `\continuedfloat` is stoping the increment of the number of the picture but when it comes to the subfigure it does nothing.

Comment: @RafaelSantos, for any comment i need more information about your document. from coment i see, that your figure numbers include section number, however this should not influence in numbering of sub figures. please, edit your question and extent showed mwe that it will demonstrate your problem. if i add sections and consider https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391514 i obtain correct and expected result.

Comment: @RafaelSantos, i edit my answer and consider most of your document preamble (all except your document class). it works, for mwe. if your test doesn't give the same result, than yo should ask author of  documentclass, that he repair its malfunction.